# How to make MVVM context binding for ChromiumWebBrowser in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, cefsharp

I am using **CefSharp.Wpf**. And my solution looks like:

[image: Solution tree]

Where **G_Hoover.Views** has reference to the **G_Hoover.ViewModels**.

Currently I am trying to create in `BrowserView.xaml` a `ChromiumWebBrowser` object, where the object is going to be binded to the property in one of the view models in **G_Hoover.ViewModels** library:

```
<DockPanel x:Name="browserViewRow" Grid.Row="1">
            <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser DataContext="{Binding WebBrowser, Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DockPanel>
```

where in my xaml data context is setted up:

```
<!--data context bindings works fine, checked-->
DataContext="{Binding BrowserViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">
```

and cefsharp namespace is like:

```
xmlns:cefSharp="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
```

In my `BrowserViewModel.cs` I am having instance of the `ChromiumWebBrowser WebBrowser` in a method called by ctor:

```
private void InitializeBrowser()
        {
            WebBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();

            WebBrowser.Address = "https://www.google.com/";
        }
private ChromiumWebBrowser webBrowser;
        public ChromiumWebBrowser WebBrowser
        {
            get
            {
                return webBrowser;
            }
            set
            {
                webBrowser = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

After loading `WebBrowser.Address` nothing happens in my view. So my question is, am I correctly binding `ChromiumWebBrowser` in my XAML, if yes, what am I doing wrong, if not, how am I supposed to do it?

Comment: Don't create the browser in code and in xaml, just create it in xaml. In general I'd suggest you create an address property on your viewmodel and bind that to the address property of the ChromiumWebBrowser.

Comment: @amaitland but if I create ChromiumWebBrowser in XAML, I can not make reference to **G_Hoover.Views** from **G_Hoover.ViewModels**, otherwise it will be circular reference. How can I bind object from XAML to instance in view model?

Comment: You are already creating an instant in xaml according to the code you've posted, then you create a second instance in code.

Comment: Start with something simple, create an address property on your viewmodel and then bind that to the address property of ChromiumWebBrowser. Don't set the datacontext of the ChromiumWebBrowser instance,  it should be inherited.

Comment: @amaitland Ok, binding address works. But in my VM I am going to define or use many times a browser's properties, or use its event handlers (ex. LoadingStateChanged). So anyway I will have to create somehow `ChromiumWebBrowser` property in my VM and bind the object in XAML to it. Do you think that there is any way do do that?

Comment: Allright, here I found best approach for MVVM, when binding from `XAML` to `IWpfWebBrowser` I have access to most of the props of the browser object: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/tree/master/CefSharp.Wpf.Example